# Check that only one of several Ansible variables is defined

Tags: ansible

I want to check that only one of several Ansible variables is defined. It seems that Ansible conditions don't support xor. The best way I've found so far is something like this:

```
  - fail:
      msg: "var1 xor var2 xor var3 must be defined"
    when: (var1 is defined | ternary(1, 0) + var2 is defined | ternary(1, 0) + var3 is defined | ternary(1, 0)) != 1
```

Dictionary version:

```
(item.get('key1') | ternary(1, 0) + item.get('key2') | ternary(1, 0) + thedict.get('key3') | ternary(1, 0)) != 1
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should count as simpler:

```
- fail:
    msg: "only one of var1, var2, or var3 must be defined"
  when: checklist | select() | list | length != 1
  vars:
    checklist:
      - "{{ var1 is defined }}"
      - "{{ var2 is defined }}"
      - "{{ var3 is defined }}"
```

Comment: Interesting, but is there a way to define this all in-line somehow, rather than adding 5 lines of code for the checklist?

Comment: Yes, there is, but I think this is cleaner.

Comment: Could you include that version, too, please?

Comment: `when: "[{{ var1 is defined }}, {{ var2 is defined }}, {{ var3 is defined }}] | select() | list | length != 1"`

Answer (score 0):

As of Ansible 2.6 there isn't simpler way IMHO. To test *list* of conditions (see [Group theory tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#group-theory-tests)) there is only **AND** (*list is all*) and **OR** (*list is any*).